# Как сохранять данные при перезагрузке страницы? JS

Tags: javascript, json

При манипуляции с элементами страницы изменяется объект. Допустим, такой:

```
var arr=[
   {"name": "Вася", "age": 20},
   {"name": "Петя", "age": 22},
   {"name": "Таня", "age": 18}
];
```

Надо каким-то образом сохранить значение этого объекта, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы, он сохранялся.

Как это можно реализовать на фронтенде? Вроде как-то с применением json. Это тестовое задание. Но я не совсем понимаю, как реализовать данное действие. Буду очень признателен за подсказку.

Comment: почитайте про куки и localStorage

Comment: Прочтите про localStorage в js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr=[
   {"name": "Вася", "age": 20},
   {"name": "Петя", "age": 22},
   {"name": "Таня", "age": 18}
];
```

Сохранение делается так

```
localStorage.setItem("myKey",JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Извлечение

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myKey"));
```

Comment: Вы этот код пробовали?

Comment: @Igor спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, Спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Сначала сделайте строку из массива/объекта `JSON.stringify(obj);`

Потом сохраните в `localStorage`

Когда будете читать значение, то распарсите обратно в нормальное состояние `JSON.parse(string);`